# Convert string output to verify each line

Tags: python, dictionary, set, tuples

I have a string that’s returned and I    want to verify that each new line is correct. I’m unsure if I want to turn it to a dictionary to verify or is there a better way?

What I really want is to verify this:

```
username-config setting = Don_1,
name = don,
age = 19,
location = west
```

I just can’t seem to get this to break out correct. Splitting the new lines makes sense but the first and last line throws me off and idk how to convert it to verify?

Or should I not even go through the hassle of converting to dict and just verify the words are in each line?

```
str=“username config setting Don_1 \n name don \n age [19] \n location west \n games dark reign”

x = str.split('\n')
print(x)

for i in x:
    print(y)
```

Output:

> username config setting Don_1
>
> name don
>
> age [19]
>
> location west
>
> games dark reign

Comment: What are you trying to verify precisely?

Comment: That ‘username config-setting’ contains Don_1, ‘name’ has don, age has [19], etc.

Comment: Does the returned string contain the '=' signs? For example, username-config setting = Don_1 or not?

Comment: No I’m basically trying to say that later in my verification.